# Encode publicKey on Java Card

Tags: java, encoding, javacard, ecdsa, pkcs#8

How to encode an ECDSA PublicKey on Java Card so that after I can decode it on another platform (e.g. sending the encoded key in a response APDU and processing it in a standard Java application)? `keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded()` on Java would do the trick with PKCS#8 encoding, but as far as I know `getEncoded()` is not available on the Java Card platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement this function like this:

**Card side:**

- 1 KeyPair.getPublicKey() --> publicKey;
- 2 publicKey.getW() --> W;
- 3 Send W to outside;

**Standard java application side:**

- 1 get W data bytes;
- 2 W data bytes --> ECPoint;
- 3 Build PublicKey with the ECPoint generated in step 2 use the class ECPublicKeySpec;
- 4 Use the public key in your application;

Answer (score 1):

`getEncoded()` method returns the key in its primary encoding format, or null if the key does not support encoding. So you don't need to use it for your goal. you simply can use down-casting to `ECPublicKey`:

```
ECPublicKey pubKey = (ECPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic()
```

The `pubKey` in the above line, is equal with output of `getEncoded()` method in Java applications.

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I know you can only send a byte array in a response APDU, and ECPublicKey is not a byte array. That was the main issue. Anyway, it looks like that unknwyshsa's answer has solved my problem.